# How to change date of calendar popup in robotium solo

Tags: android, robotium

[image]

Hi i want to select any random date on this popup calendar using robotium solo.
Below is the code in which i have managed to get all views on my screen and 
14 is linearlayout for dates and 15 is id for ok button. But i am not able to select any random date.

```
            solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(R.id.date));
            ArrayList<View> vs = solo.getCurrentViews();
            View dayPicker = vs.get(14);
            solo.clickOnView(vs.get(14));
            solo.clickOnView(vs.get(15));
```

Thanks in  advanced!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can click specific date by it's text like:

```
solo.clickOnText("10");
```

No matter which language you are using, numbers doesnt change. So you just click it by text, you dont need to random it.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get your DatePicker, cast it to ViewGrop, and then use getChildAt(int i).

```
ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) solo.getView(R.id.DatePrickerEXAMPLEID);
```

or via activity:

```
ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) solo.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(R.id.DatePrickerEXAMPLEID);
```

And then try to find needed child with

```
View child = v.getChildAt(2);
```

Not sure this will help, but it worse trying. 
Good luck =)